# Disabling deleting reusable blocks except on the reusable block manager

Tags: block-editor

I am using reusable blocks to add repeatable content on all my posts. This is not something that I can automate because the position varies from post to post. I have to edit thousands of all posts to do this.

The problem here is that twice I've accidentally deleted the reusable blocks entirely when I had meant to delete them from just one post. Luckily I automatically backup twice a day, but both times it still meant losing a day's work.

Is there way to disable deleting reusable blocks altogether except by going to the reusable blocks manager?